# How can I sort an ArrayList with Objects that have a name and "strenght"? (Java)

Tags: java, arraylist

I've got an `ArrayList` with `Object`s in it. The Objects have a `String name` and a `String style` and an `int strength`.

I would like to sort by name in my `ArrayList` then list it to the standard output.

How can I do this with a method called `NameComparator`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement a [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html):

```
public class NameComparator implements Comparator<MyClass> {
    @Override
    public int compare (MyClass c1, MyClass c2) {
        return c1.getName().compareTo(c2.getName());
    }
}
```

Then, you can use it in conjuction with [`Collections.sort(List)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)):

```
List<MyClass> list = <initialize and fill with data>;
Collections.sort(list, new NameComparator());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Collections.sort(T[], Comparator c) using your NameComparator comparator.
Learn more [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html)

Answer (score 0):

you can use java Comparator/Comparable to sort your list

example employee class

example :->

```
class MySalaryComp implements Comparator<Empl>{

    @Override
    public int compare(Empl e1, Empl e2) {
        if(e1.getSalary() < e2.getSalary()){
            return 1;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

and Employee class

```
class Empl{

    private String name;
    private int salary;

    public Empl(String n, int s){
        this.name = n;
        this.salary = s;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }
    public void setSalary(int salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return "Name: "+this.name+"-- Salary: "+this.salary;
    }
}
```

now you can use this comparator as

```
 Collections.sort(list,new MySalaryComp());
```

Answer (score 0):

You write you own `Comparator` class, then you sort the `List` with `Collections.sort(list, new MyComparator());`

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a `Comparator<Blah>`, where `Blah` is the class name of what's in your `ArrayList` (i.e., it's an `ArrayList<Blah>`).

It'll look something like this:

```
public class NameComparator implements Comparator<Blah> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Blah x, Blah y) {
        return x.getName().compareTo(y.getName());
    }
}
```

Note that this assumes that the `name` property is never `null`, which may or may not be true in your case. Once you've done this, you can use `Collections.sort()` to sort your `ArrayList`.

Then, to print it out, you'll want to iterate over the elements:

```
for (Blah b: myArrayListBlah)
    System.out.println(b.getName());
```

or similar, depending on quite how you want it to come out.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your model class you have to change the signature of your class and implement  the above methods :

```
class YourClass implements Comparator<YourClass>, Comparable<YourClass>{
   // Overriding the compareTo method
   public int compareTo(Dog d){
      return (this.name).compareTo(d.name);
   }

   // Overriding the compare method to sort the age 
   public int compare(YourClass d, YourClass d1){
      return d.strength - d1.strength;
   }
```

and at the point where you want to make the sort you have to call :

```
      // Sorts the array list using comparator
      Collections.sort(list, new YourClass());
      System.out.println(" ");
      for(YourClass a: list)//printing the sorted list of strengths
         System.out.print(a.getStrength() +"  : "+ a.getStrength() + ", ");
```

Answer (score 0):

**Test.java**

```
package com.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyFile myFile1 = new MyFile("square", "bold", 1);
        MyFile myFile2 = new MyFile("rect", "bold", 2);
        MyFile myFile3 = new MyFile("circle", "italic", 3);
        MyFile myFile4 = new MyFile("pyramid", "bold", 4);

        List<MyFile> myFiles = new ArrayList<MyFile>();
        myFiles.add(myFile1);
        myFiles.add(myFile2);
        myFiles.add(myFile3);
        myFiles.add(myFile4);

        Collections.sort(myFiles, new Comparator<MyFile>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(MyFile o1, MyFile o2) {

                if (o1.getName() == o2.getName()) {
                    return 0;
                }

                return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
            }
        });

        for (int i = 0 ; i < myFiles.size() ; i++) {
            System.out.println(myFiles.get(i).getName());
        }
    }
}
```

**MyFile .java**

```
package com.*;

public class MyFile {

    private String name;

    private String style;

    private int    strength;

    public MyFile(String name, String style, int strength) {
        this.name = name;
        this.style = style;
        this.strength = strength;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getStyle() {
        return style;
    }

    public void setStyle(String style) {
        this.style = style;
    }

    public int getStrength() {
        return strength;
    }

    public void setStrength(int strength) {
        this.strength = strength;
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
circle
pyramid
rect
square
```